Uniqueness of a properly convex projective domain divisible by a group
Let us say that a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ of ${\rm PGL}(n+1, \mathbb R)$ is convex divisible if there exists an invariant properly convex domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{RP}^n$, on which $\Gamma$ acts cocompactly. They were actively studied by plenty of authors, e.g., by Yves Benoist. Is the domain $\Omega$ unique for a given $\Gamma$? I have just scrolled several surveys and papers on the topic, but somehow did not find a discussion of this very basic matter.
UPD: what is about when $\Gamma$ is Gromov-hyperbolic? (So, $\Omega$ is strictly convex.)

No, think about discrete free abelian groups of rank $n$.

@MoisheKohan, please note that a properly convex domain has its closure in an affine chart. May I ask, what are the examples then?

Just take a rank 2 discrete subgroup of diagonal 3x3 matrices of determinant 1 and positive disgonal entries. There will be 4 triangles in the projective plane invariant under the action.

Take a discrete rank $n$ free abelian subgroup $\Gamma$ of the group of diagonal matrices in $SL(n+1, \mathbb R)$ with positive diagonal entries. The group $\Gamma$ will preserve each open coordinate orthant $C_i, i=1,...,2^{n+1}$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. The  projectivization $P(C_i)\subset \mathbb R P^n$ of each $C_i$ is open and properly convex: There will be $2^n$ of these domains in $\mathbb R P^n$. The group $\Gamma$ preserves each $P(C_i)$, acts on it properly discontinuously and cocompactly.
Edit: As for your update (which starts to sound like a fishing expedition). Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a hyperbolic group acting on a properly convex open subset $D\subset \mathbb R P^n$, equivalently, the closure of $D$ is strictly convex (the boundary does not contain any nondegenerate line segments). Then the boundary of $D$ is equivariantly homeomorphic to the Gromov-boundary  of $\Gamma$ and, accordingly, the action of $\Gamma$ on the closure of $D$ satisfies the convergence property: Every unbounded sequence in $\Gamma$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on compact to constant in $\partial D$ away from a point in $\partial D$. In particular, each infinite order element of $\Gamma$ has a unique dominant eigenvector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ corresponding to its attractive fixed point in $\partial D$. Furthermore, attractive fixed points are dense in $\partial D$. Assume that $\Gamma$ acts
on two distinct properly convex domains $D_1, D_2$ in $\mathbb R P^n$ properly discontinuously and cocompactly. Then, by the above density observation, $\partial D_1=\partial D_2$. This is impossible for strictly convex domains.

Indeed, thanks! Do you know, what is about non-equivalent domains? (By a projective transformation.) And about Gromov hyperbolic subgroups?

I am unsure. My guess is that in the GH (strictly convex) case the domain is unique. It is so if $n=3$. @Roman

Yes, it is unique in this case, but I do not know an easy proof. It is probably in the literature.
